# Error importing data from MySQL to Hive using Sqoop. Is there somehow to define table name to --map-column-hive parameter?

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop

I'm trying to import a large database with tons of tables and columns from MySQL to Hive using Sqoop.

**Versions**

---

MySQL 8.0, Sqoop 1.4.7, Hive 3.1.1

---

To achieve that I've used first the following command line:

```
sqoop-import-all-tables
--connect jdbc:mysql://IP:porta/mydatabase
--username myusername
-p
--hive-import
--direct
```

But there are some incompatibility between data type in MySQL and Hive, and I received the following error message:

```
ERROR tool.ImportAllTablesTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Hive does not support the SQL type for column rowguid.
```

So, looking at [Sqoop 1.4.7 documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html), I noticed that there is a parameter `--map-column-hive <name-of-column-to-map>`. So, I added it to my command line: `--map-column-hive rowguid=binary` and got this new error:

```
ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No column by the name rowguid found while importing data
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No column by the name rowguid found while importing data
```

This error happens when it's importing the next table after the one containing rowguid column.

My database has several tables and tons of columns. When I execute the above command line, it goes normal until it throws me an error related to missing column rowguid. Of course, this mapping should be done just on the specific table where this column exists, not in all tables.

Is there a way to define `table-name + column-name` in `--map-column-hive` parameter? Or another way to step over this issue? Maybe importing all tables changing automatically the data types?

Comment: As an idea, have you tried this? ````sqoop import-all-tables -Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true````

Comment: I'll try. Thanks. What is this parameter for?

Comment: The property ````Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true```` is required when  there is a index column which is of text type.